# Responsive imagery inside fixed height/width container

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive-images

Currently I am having trouble with some images losing their quality when i put them inside a fixed height container (300px at larger screens). When i resize the window they get more squashed and then it hits a media query i made and it still doesn't look good. I have searched online but cannot find exactly what I am looking for. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong please? I just want them to keep the quality as well resizing to fit the screen.

Thanks!

```css
.an-image {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.an-image:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .image-gallery {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .image-gallery .content {
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: center;
    background: none;
  }
  .image-gallery .container-content {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
  .an-image {
    flex: 33%;
    /* assumes three images */
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    /* just so you can see what's happening */
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .an-image:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .an-image img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .an-image {
    flex: 33%;
    /* assumes three images */
    padding: 0;
    height: 20%;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .an-image img {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    max-height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="images" class="image-gallery container">
  <div class="container-content">
    <h2>Image Gallery</h2>
    <div class="content">

      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
      </div>


    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Of course they get squashed because of the defined height of `300px`. You have multiple options, you can leave it like that and add `object-fit: cover`, but that will crop them when needed, or you can just let it "run" naturally without the defined height, with the `display: block; width: 100%`, which of course will also keep their exact ratio, without cropping.

Comment: Thank you! That works perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/Hjorth/pen/KRdeWL)

You need to use the attribute `auto` on either the  `width` or the `height` to make it resize correctly. Look at the CSS.

Comment: Is there any way i could stretch these images out so its more full width? Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Use larger images :)

Answer (score 0):

You are giving the image a height property with a width property. This way your image will scale and the resolution will change.

```css
.an-image {
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.an-image:nth-child(2n) {
  background: #ddd;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  .image-gallery {
    background: transparent;
  }
  .image-gallery .content {
    display: flex;
    text-align: left;
    justify-content: center;
    background: none;
  }
  .image-gallery .container-content {
    max-width: 1000px;
  }
  .an-image {
    flex: 33%;
    /* assumes three images */
    padding: 0;
    max-height: 300px;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    border: 1px solid red;
    /* just so you can see what's happening */
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .an-image:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;
  }
  .an-image img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .an-image {
    flex: 33%;
    /* assumes three images */
    padding: 0;
    height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background: none;
    max-height: auto; 
    padding-bottom: 20px;
  }
  .an-image img {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
```

```html
<section id="images" class="image-gallery container">
  <div class="container-content">
    <h2>Image Gallery</h2>
    <div class="content">

      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
      </div>
      
      <div class="an-image">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" />
      </div>


    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I have tried editing this and still no luck :( I am new to development sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Question answered, needed to remove the fixed height on the image and make some flowing mods like width 100% etc!